# How can I get an ActionBar's TextView?

Tags: android

I can get an `ActionBar`'s `view` using [getCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#getCustomView%28%29). Is there a way to get its `TextView` from that?

Comment: Are you trying to set the Title/Subtitle? Not sure what you mean by 'it's TextView'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any way that is going to be reliable across OS versions and devices.

If you are attempting to set the title of the action bar, please use `setTitle()` on `ActionBar`. If you are trying to style the title, you should be able to do that via a theme.

Or, hide the title and render your own via `setCustomView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try recursively? (*might not be a good solution though!*)

```
static List<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();

public static <T> void searchRecursively(View parent, Class<T> clazz)
{
    if(clazz.isInstance(parent)) textViews.add(clazz.cast(parent));
    if(parent instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) parent;
        int count = vg.getChildCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
            searchRecursively(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
searchRecursively(theView, TextView.class);
```